# Prove the following statement using the contrapositive method. If $ n^2 $ is divisible by 3 then n is divisible by 3.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove the following statement using the contrapositive method. If $ n^2 $ is divisible by 3 then n is divisible by 3.

I tried using contrapositive method by assuming if not b then not a, i.e., if n is not divisible by 3 then $ n^2$ is not divisible by 3. and prove it.

Is this the correct way to do it or am I doing it wrong?

If anyone could layout an explanation could be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Your statement of the contrapositive is correct. Where are you stuck in proving it ?

Comment: I'm stuck at the proof part. I'm uncertain how to prove it.

Comment: **Hint :** If $n$ is not dividible by $3$, either there exists $k$ such that $n=3k+1$, either there exists $k$ such that $n=3k+2$.

Comment: Thanks! It was very much helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two facts to note:

If $n$ is not divisible by 3, then $n\equiv1 \ \text{mod} \ 3$ or $n\equiv2 \ \text{mod} \ 3.$

If $a\equiv b \ \text{mod} \ n$, then $a^2 \equiv b^2 \ \text{mod} \ n$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score -1):

With contrapositive method：

If n is not divisible by 3, let n = 3m + k, where m, k are integers and k=1,2 only.
好
Then
$n^2$  = $(3m+k)^2$=9$m^2$+6mk+$k^2$.

If k=1, $n^2$  = $(3m+k)^2$=9$m^2$+6mk+1=3(3$m^2$+2mk)+1, not divisible by 3.

If k=2, $n^2$  = $(3m+k)^2$=9$m^2$+6mk+3+1= 3(3$m^2$+2mk+1)+1,  not divisible by 3.

This is in contradictory with the assumption $n^2$ is divisible by 3. So n must be divisible by 3.

Comment: A contradiction proof is different than contrapositive proof, although they will start the same. Ie if proving p -> q, then assume not q. Contraposition will prove not p. For contradiction, something else happens that's contradictory, you may prove that if not q then q. Or 1=0, or a variety of other things.

Comment: Ie, it was not necessary to assume p and saying not p is a contradiction. If you did that you assumed both not q and p to lead to a 'contradiction' which is technically incorrect

Comment: Thanks! I get it now